# Powershell creating a CSV from JSON data not working

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to grab a list of completed pull requests from Azure DevOps and dump the data to a CSV file. Should be easy... except powershell's ConvertTo-Csv won't cooperate.

Here's the command:

```
az repos pr list --organization https://dev.azure.com/hahahaha `
    --project main --status completed `
    --top 10 --skip 0 `
    --query "[*].{pullRequestId:pullRequestId, createdBy:createdBy.displayName,creationDate: creationDate,repository: repository.name, closedDate: closedDate}" `
    | ConvertFrom-Json `
    | ConvertTo-Csv
```

Here's the garbage output:

```
#TYPE System.Object[]
"Count","Length","LongLength","Rank","SyncRoot","IsReadOnly","IsFixedSize","IsSynchronized"
"10","10","10","1","System.Object[]","False","True","False"
```

What's annoying is if instead of ConvertTo-Csv I do format-table I get good output. Here's the updated command:

```
az repos pr list --organization https://dev.azure.com/hahahaha `
    --project main --status completed `
    --top 10 --skip 0 `
    --query "[*].{pullRequestId:pullRequestId, createdBy:createdBy.displayName,creationDate: creationDate,repository: repository.name, closedDate: closedDate}" `
    | ConvertFrom-Json `
    | Format-Table
```

Here's the good output:

```
closedDate                       createdBy        creationDate                     pullRequestId repository
----------                       ---------        ------------                     ------------- ----------
2024-03-26T13:50:27.781982+00:00 dddd dddddd      2024-03-22T20:33:39.322343+00:00          3966 zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
2024-03-26T13:07:43.264020+00:00 eeeeee eeeeeeeee 2024-03-26T12:13:30.279093+00:00          3987 wwwwwwwwwwwwwww
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you share the raw JSON output from `az repos ...`? FWIW inserting `Write-Output` might do the trick to flatten the outer array, eg.: `...|ConvertFrom-Json |Write-Output |ConvertTo-Csv`

Comment: You can try putting the whole az command in parentheses so it finishes first.  Note you can continue a line with a pipe `|` symbol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a Windows Powershell\Desktop\5.1 problem(might be a bug).

I'm going to guess you cannot simply swith to Core\7x, which would resolve the issue.

use this, then:

```
az repos pr list --organization https://dev.azure.com/hahahaha `
    --project main --status completed `
    --top 10 --skip 0 `
    --query '[*].{pullRequestId:pullRequestId, createdBy:createdBy.displayName,creationDate: creationDate,repository: repository.name, closedDate: closedDate}' |
    ConvertFrom-Json | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Syncroot |
    ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: For some reason I just though Windows would automatically keep PowerShell up to date. Thanks a heap!!